# Springboot application - Issue in fetching tomcat threads and datasources

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jmxtrans

I am using jmxtrans as a agent in java arguments and passing the jmxtrans-agent.xml for the metrics. Currently, i am getting the metrics for JVM ( JVM memory pools) But i dont see any metrics for threads and datasources. Can you please suggest for object and attributes to be used. I am using tomcat 8 server.

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmxtrans-agent>
   <invocations>
      <invocation objectName="java.lang:type=Memory" operation="gc" resultAlias="jvm.gc" />
   </invocations>
   <queries>
      <!-- OS -->
      <query objectName="java.lang:type=OperatingSystem" attribute="SystemLoadAverage" resultAlias="os.systemLoadAverage" />
      <!-- JVM -->
      <query objectName="java.lang:type=Memory" attribute="HeapMemoryUsage" key="used" resultAlias="jvm.heapMemoryUsage.used" />
      <query objectName="java.lang:type=Memory" attribute="HeapMemoryUsage" key="committed" resultAlias="jvm.heapMemoryUsage.committed" />
      <query objectName="java.lang:type=Memory" attribute="NonHeapMemoryUsage" key="used" resultAlias="jvm.nonHeapMemoryUsage.used" />
      <query objectName="java.lang:type=Memory" attribute="NonHeapMemoryUsage" key="committed" resultAlias="jvm.nonHeapMemoryUsage.committed" />
      <query objectName="java.lang:type=ClassLoading" attribute="LoadedClassCount" resultAlias="jvm.loadedClasses" />
      <query objectName="java.lang:type=Threading" attribute="ThreadCount" resultAlias="jvm.thread" />
      <!-- TOMCAT -->
      <query objectName="Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=*" attribute="requestCount" resultAlias="tomcat.requestCount" />
      <query objectName="Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=*" attribute="errorCount" resultAlias="tomcat.errorCount" />
      <query objectName="Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=*" attribute="processingTime" resultAlias="tomcat.processingTime" />
      <query objectName="Catalina:type=GlobalRequestProcessor,name=*" attribute="bytesSent" resultAlias="tomcat.bytesSent" />
      <query objectName="Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=*" attribute="currentThreadCount" resultAlias="tomcat7-connectors" />
   <query objectName="Catalina:type=DataSource,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name=*" attribute="numActive" />
   
   <query objectName="Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=*" attribute="currentThreadCount" resultAlias="tomcat.currentThreadCount" />
   <query objectName="Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name=*" attribute="currentThreadsBusy" resultAlias="tomcat.currentThreadsBusy" />
   
      <!--<query objectName="jboss.as.datasources.OracleDS.pool" attribute="ActiveCount" resultAlias="Active.Pool.Count" />
      <query objectName="jboss.as:subsystem=datasources,xa-data-source=OracleDS,statistics=pool" attribute="MaxUsedCount" />
      <query objectName="jboss.as:subsystem=datasources,xa-data-source=OracleDS,statistics=pool" attribute="AvailableCount" resultAlias="foo" />
      <query objectName="jboss.as.expr:xa-data-source=OracleDS,statistics=pool" attribute="AvailableCount" resultAlias="foo" />-->
      <!-- APPLICATION -->
      <query objectName="Catalina:type=Manager,context=/,host=localhost" attribute="activeSessions" resultAlias="application.activeSessions" />
   </queries>
   <outputWriter class="org.jmxtrans.agent.StatsDOutputWriter">
      <host>server</host>
      <port>8125</port>
      <tags>jmx_</tags>
   </outputWriter>
   <collectIntervalInSeconds>10</collectIntervalInSeconds>
</jmxtrans-agent>
```